# Find the matrix representation of $L$ with respect to $P$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\ P := \{p_1, p_2\}$ be the bases of $\ P_1$ given by

$$\ P_1(t) = 1,\  P_2(t) = t$$ and let $\ L: P_1 \to P_1$ given by

$$\ (L(p))(t) = tp(0)+(2-t)p'(t),$$

then the question asks o find the matrix representation of $\ L $ with respect to $\ P$.

My  intuition says that we put $\ P_1$ and $\ P_2$, namely $1$ and $t$ in this case, into $\ L$, yielding

$\ L(1) = 1+(2-t) = 3-t), L(t) = 2-t$,

and then arranging this as a matrix yielding the solution:

\begin{bmatrix}3&-1\\2&-1\end{bmatrix}

Would appreciate some verification on whether this is right. Apologies in advance for the lack of formatting.

Comment: When you get the matrix of LT you can always check does Lx=L(x)

Comment: @CTSnake Firstly, thank you very much for formatting the question for me. Secondly, sorry but I don't quite follow with what you're trying to say there, can you elaborate this for me please?

Comment: you take some vector $\ x\in{P_1}$ and multiply the matrix by it if the result is the same as the result you'll get when you pass x to the linear operator then you did a good job

Comment: @CTSnake Alright, if you could just bare with me while I run through an example with you please.

I will take 3t as my x as you mention:

When I put 3t into L I get:

L(3t) = 6-3t

and then, the matrix form of 3t is (0 3) right? Then

(0 3) multiplied by my matrix yields 6, -3 as a column vector.

So my answer for the matrix should be right?

Comment: @t hesmallprint sure

Comment: @CTSnake Ah, thank you very much then!

Comment: the usual notation is like this $\ \pmatrix{3&2\\-1&-1}$ and for your vector $\ [0\ 3]^T$

Comment: Ah okay, gotcha. Again, thank you so much for your help.